# Image overlapping a div

Tags: html, css, position

I want to make like this:

[image: View Image]

Here the circle is an image.

I tried this. But when I resize the window size the image circle gets shifted changes its postion. How can I fix that.

```
<div class="main">
    <img src=''>
    <div>Text Text Text</div>
</div>


.main {       
        background-color: #fbd449;
        border-radius: 4.5px;
        padding: 0.5rem 3rem;
        position: relative;
        margin-left: 9rem;
}

img {
        position: absolute;
        background-color: chocolate;
        width: 9rem;
        height: 9rem;
        top: -12%;
        border-radius: 50%;
        left: -20%;
}
```

Also for smaller screen the div height increases but the image is of same height. If possible could you also help me in this problem too.

Comment: Sorry, could not upload the image properly as I am a new user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is solution i think you are looking for..

if you use `%` then output will be different in mobile device.

in class `.main` and `img` you can change height and width as per your choice

```css
.main {
  background-color: #fbd449;
  border-radius: 4.5px;
  padding: 0.5rem 3rem;
  position: fixed;
  margin-left: 9rem;
  top: 25px;
  left:-5px;
  height: 100px;
  width: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: chocolate;
  width: 9rem;
  height: 9rem;
  top: 12px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <img src=''>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @sajgkh becasue percentage is not good idea mostly it is used for responsive design but here you are using position fixed css property also you can find out from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31728022/why-is-percentage-height-not-working-on-my-div/31728182#:~:text=Working%20with%20the%20CSS%20height%20property%20and%20percentage%20values&text=If%20you%20have%20not%20set,by%20content%20and%20other%20properties.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it in fixed position at all times then probably using % is not the best idea. Copy and paste the code below instead of your CSS and see if it helps you. It's not exact replica of your shared image, but you can play with correct sizes and positioning to get it right for your site.

```
.main { 
  background-color: #fbd449;
  border-radius: 4.5px;
  padding: 0.5rem 3rem;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 9rem;
  width:12rem;
  height: 3rem;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: chocolate;
  width: 7rem;
  height: 7rem;
  margin-left:-4rem;
  margin-top:-2rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.main > div {
  padding-left:4rem
}
```

Comment: For main you have given both relative and absolute

Comment: Thanks for the heads up sajgkh! Just edited my code to correct it.

Answer (score 0):

Made few changes to the css

```
.main {       
        background-color: #fbd449;
        border-radius: 4.5px;
        padding: 0.5rem 5rem 0.5rem 9rem;
        position: relative;
        margin:2rem 9rem 0;
        width:100%;
        height:7rem;
        border-radius:10px;
        box-sizing:border-box;
}

img {
        position: absolute;
        background-color: chocolate;
        width: 9rem;
        height: 9rem;
        top: -1rem;
        border-radius: 50%;
        left: -1.5rem;
}
```